# How to change the status in Google Chat to busy when in Google meet?

Tags: javascript, google-api, chat, status, google-hangouts

I need to change my Google Chat status frequently because of daily meetings, which I do mostly in Google Meet. Is there a way to change my status as busy(programmatically) whenever I'm in Google Meet?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to achieve it? I would be interested in collaborate with anybody to get a solution for this.

Comment: As Eric said *Google Meet does not offer a public API*.  But yea I manage to achieve it using *googleapis* calendar API and created a simple VUE app for the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Meet does not offer a public API, this means that the only way would be to use a browser extension. This extension could be able to detect Google Meet calls and react by changing the status. As the Google Chat API does not support setting the status as far as I am concerned, using a something like puppeteer or a browser extension would be the only way.

Comment: Thanks! @Eric. Can you suggest some extension?

Comment: No problem! :) As far as I know, there is no extension like that. You could write your own - for example for Chrome: [Chrome Extensions Getting Started Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/getstarted/) From my experience, it is fairly straightforward to do so.